# WARN (org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext:333) - afterTransactionCompletion() was never called

Tags: database, performance, hibernate, postgresql

I am using hibernate as ORM when i checked my logs (catalina.out)

I am getting this warning so many times

```
WARN   (org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext:333) - afterTransactionCompletion() was never called
```

Can any one please help me to solve this warning...?

what is the meaning of that warning and when it occurs ??

Comment: I changed the tag from [postgresql] to [hibernate] because there is nothing related to PostgreSQL in the question -- this is a Hibernate message, apparently related to improper transaction management at that level. Sorry I don't have a detailed answer, but having the right tag might help attract someone who does.

Comment: @kgrittn - yes i am sorry for that ,Due to some reason i add postgresql as tag , and thanks for editing it

Comment: Are you using c3p0 for your connection pooling? The (very old) thread at the following indicates that could be an issue: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=928136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file JDBCContext.java source file is the following comment

```
/**
 * We cannot rely upon this method being called! It is only
 * called if we are using Hibernate Transaction API.
 */
```

This means, the method afterTransactionCompletion() normally is called by the hibernate transaction API, for example Session.flush() or Transaction.commit(). It seems somewhere in your program it can happen a transaction is not ended regularly. We can't tell you where, because we don't know your code.